# Why can't load css file with setting `APP_DEBUG=0`?

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony 6.4:
I put file CSS in `assets` folder:
[image]

In file twig:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">
```

In `.env` file , If setting  `APP_DEBUG=1`, my site working ok.

But If setting  `APP_DEBUG=0`, my site occur this error in `console` of browser:

> localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/assets/css/style-02b3f8e0a52008b8c152b52915ebf0a3.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Why can't load CSS file with setting `APP_DEBUG=0`?

Comment: Have you checked the response you are getting for that asset? Looks like you are getting an error HTML page instead of the CSS file. Checking the actual error would be very helpful.

Comment: Maybe an webpack build error ?

Comment: i not use webpack, i using css <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">